# Custom UIControl always sends nil UIEvent objects

Tags: objective-c, ios, uicontrol, uievent

I have a class that derives from UIControl in which I monitor the touchesBegan/Moved/Ended/Cancelled events. Within those events I call the same events on both super and next responder like so:

```
[self.nextResponder touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
[self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
```

I have a parent control that owns a table view. The cells in the table view each contain one of my custom controls. In order to respond to a click I assign a selector to the control when I am creating it and adding it to the table view cell like so:

```
[myControl addTarget:self action:@selector(myControlTap:withEvent:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
[cell.contentView addSubview:myControl];
```

The parent control's selector looks like this:

```
- (void)myControlTap:(id)sender withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
     //UIEvent is always null!
}
```

Can someone tell me why UIEvent is always nil? If I use an instance of UIButton instead of my custom UIControl then UIEvent is not nil. Furthermore, if I don't call sendActionsForControlEvents in my control then the parent control will never receive any event notifications.

Comment: Just to confirm, what is the output when you put `NSLog(@"%@", event);` in your `myControlTap:withEvent:` method?

Answer (score -1):

Change "withEvent" to "forEvent" in the method and the selector.